# Switch AirPods from macOS to iOS 11

Tags: macos, ios, bluetooth, airpods

Using my AirPods with my Mac is easy:

1. Check the `Show volume in menu bar` checkbox in `System Preferences` > `Sound`.
2. Ready the AirPods near the Mac.
3. Click the Volume menu bar icon, and choose your AirPods.

**How to regain control of the AirPods in iOS 11 such as on an iPhone?**

The swipe-from-bottom controls have changed radically. So the old iOS 10 approach is gone.

Supposedly, in the new swipe-from-bottom controls, you can use the Apple Music widget to gain control of the AirPods. That's annoying as I am not an Apple Music customer, so the extra taps are out-of-my-way. But anyways, that approach fails. Here is a screenshot of iPhone > Control Center > Apple Music widget > Upper-right corner icon > list of devices, showing iPhone and AppleTV but no AirPods.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AirPods have had issues with iCloud account syncing across devices in the past. So I would first try pairing under bluetooth settings on iPhone directly and if that doesn't work (may fix account issues?) I would hold the button to reset the AirPods and then re-pair them to the iPhone and see if they show up on your Mac.

Note: both devices must be signed into the same iCloud account for easy connecting. Otherwise you'll connect manually as you would to other BT devices.

Comment: The iPhone "Settings" panel for "Bluetooth" showed only one item, identified only by some odd sequence of digits and/or letters. I tapped the "i"-in-circle icon, tapped "Forget this device", all while having the AirPods case lid open. Then went in and out of the "Bluetooth" settings again. Some message appeared asking to re-pair by holding the button on the back of the AirPods case. With lid closed, nothing happened. With lid open, the iPhone & AirPods re-paired quickly. Now using the AirPods again with iPhone, good! But now I'm scared to ever switch again to Mac or AppleTV. :-(

Comment: Works across iPhone, Mac, AppleTV seamlessly for me. Give it a shot, it's one of the benefits of the Apple ecosystem. Worst case you can re-pair using the button on the back!

Answer (score 2):

With the AirPods near your iPhone (or I put them in my ears and pick up the phone).

- Swipe up from the bottom of the screen to show the Control Centre.
- Tap on the top right corner of the Music control to show the list of devices.
- Tap on "Basil's AirPods".

Comment: Nope. AirPods in ear, iPhone > Control Center > Apple Music widget > Upper-right corner icon > list of devices, showing iPhone and AppleTV, but no AirPods. [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/WCHrRDF.jpg)